# how to use azure speaker recognition api in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-api

I am using python 2.7. I want to use speaker identification. I want to know how can i Enroll and get profile identified.

Can anyone send me code and module required to be downloaded. It would work by changing audio and subscription key.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please go to
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/
and follow the 'API' link (on the row of links that starts with "Explore Speaker Recognition:"). It will take you to API documentation, starting right at the first topic about how to create enrollment. Each topic page has a code sample at the bottom in various languages, incl. Python.